# Worker died/Worker disconnected Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to set up a multi-model endpoint (or more accurately re-set it up as I am pretty sure it was working a while ago, on an earlier version of sagemaker) to do language translation. But am constantly met with the same issue. This is what I am trying to run (from a notebook on sagemaker):

```py
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.pytorch.model import PyTorchModel
from sagemaker.predictor import JSONSerializer, JSONDeserializer

role = 'role_name...'
pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(model_data='s3://foreign-language-models/opus-mt-ROMANCE-en.tar.gz',
                             role=role,
                             framework_version="1.3.1",
                             py_version="py3",
                             source_dir="code",
                             entry_point="deploy_multi_model.py")
x = pytorch_model.predictor_cls(endpoint_name='language-translation')
x.serializer = JSONSerializer()
x.deserializer = JSONDeserializer()

x.predict({'model_name': 'opus-mt-ROMANCE-en', 'text': ["Hola que tal?"]})
```

To which I am met with the error:

```
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from model with message "{
  "code": 500,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": "Worker died."
}
```

And when I investigate the the logs the error links to the only notable one says:

```
epollEventLoopGroup-4-1 com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerThread - 9000 Worker disconnected. WORKER_MODEL_LOADED
```

But I cannot figure out why this is happening.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is currently driving me insane! And if you need any more information from me to help, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for this??

Comment: @RahulKedia, hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77414545/1444246) approach helps! Also would like to know the exact error you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old and may not be answered, however, the way to proceed when faced with these problems is very straightforward:

This is the service unavailability message due to a generic internal error precisely. You should open the full endpoint logs from [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/it/cloudwatch/) and see where it broke down. The cause can be of any type.

To debug the problem, reach the logs directly by clicking on "View logs" in the training process screen or by going to CloudWatch at the path:

`CloudWatch / Log groups /aws/sagemaker/TrainingJobs / <your_job_name>`.

If the problem occurs right away, it could be related to incorrect loading of model data or passing inference data incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @giuseppe-la-gualano, the cloudwatch errors in this scenario could be related to limitations with the SageMaker Endpoints in terms of handling payloads/responses beyond their standard limits.

### Potential issues

[Payload size for inference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/ml-service-restrictions-and-limits.html#ml-payload-size-for-inference)

For an endpoint, limit the maximum size of the input data per invocation to 6 MB. This value can't be adjusted.

For batch transform, the maximum size of the input data per invocation is 100 MB. This value can't be adjusted

In case of such error, you will find CloudWatch logs for your SageMaker endpoint with the errors such as follows:

`2023-11-03T05:13:06,763 [ERROR] epollEventLoopGroup-4-1 com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerThread - Unknown exception`

Response size exceeds limit: `io.netty.handler.codec.CorruptedFrameException: Message size exceed limit: 6654978`

or the payload size exceeds the limit: as stated [here](/questions/74853626/exceeding-size-limit-with-sagemaker-endpoint)

In my case the response of the inference exceeded the 6MB limit as a result of inference.

### How to get around with this.

The way forward could be to use [async inference endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/async-inference.html).

- You build the request and place the request on the s3 and obtain the location
- You point the prediction to look for input payload located on s3
- During the async endpoint creation, you also specifiy where the inference could place your large size output to, in the form of a s3 location. This is typically done in your Async Inference Config for your endpoint.
- Your prediction, if generating largefiles can place those results on s3 and could just provide the s3 location of the large file in the prediction response.
- The prediction will quickly give you a response that contains various details such as Output location, Failure location, InferenceId among other info for tracking purposes.

```json
{
  "ResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "GUID",
    "HTTPStatusCode": 202,
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "x-amzn-requestid": "GUID",
      "x-amzn-sagemaker-outputlocation": "s3://location/result.out",
      "x-amzn-sagemaker-failurelocation": "s3://location/file-error.out",
      "date": "Fri, 03 Nov 2023 05:45:51 GMT",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "content-length": "54",
      "connection": "keep-alive"
    },
    "RetryAttempts": 0
  },
  "OutputLocation": "s3://location/result.out",
  "FailureLocation": "s3://location/file-error.out",
  "InferenceId": "GUID"
}
```

- You can also optionally configure SNS to notify the status once the prediction is generated

You can look for the presence of output or error and take actions accordingly.